# Postgres returning in-correct results with distance join queries

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I created a table containing locations along with their spatial coordinates expressed in (latitude, longitude (in degrees)) in postgres. Commands which I used for the same are:

I inserted spatial coordinates as (longitude, latitude) in postgres

I created a table containing locations along with their spatial coordinates expressed in (latitude, longitude (in degrees)) in postgres. Commands which I used for the same are:

```
CREATE TABLE spatialTest(
  name character varying(100),
  the_geo geography
);
\copy spatialTest(name,the_geo) FROM 'testSpatial.csv' DELIMITERS E'\t' CSV;
```

testSpatial.csv contains the following values:

```
A   SRID=4326;POLYGON((0.178773 -127.681841,0.178711 -127.681962,0.179125 -127.682083,0.179176 -127.682006,0.179153 -127.681986,0.179143 -127.681962,0.179147 -127.681935,0.179166 -127.681913,0.179195 -127.681897,0.179244 -127.681886,0.179284 -127.681887,0.179336 -127.681904,0.179464 -127.681757,0.179489 -127.681736,0.179429 -127.681680,0.179370 -127.681516,0.179221 -127.681331,0.179184 -127.681185,0.179051 -127.681264,0.178822 -127.681499,0.178761 -127.681698,0.178796 -127.681703,0.178839 -127.681721,0.178857 -127.681736,0.178861 -127.681740,0.178871 -127.681756,0.178873 -127.681782,0.178859 -127.681809,0.178843 -127.681825,0.178812 -127.681839,0.178773 -127.681841))
B   SRID=4326;POINT(0.628912 -127.700922)
```

Now I want to find all spatial locations which are within a distance of 50 km of each other. For doing so I used the following command:

```
select s1.name, s2.name  from spatialTest s1, 
     spatialTest s2  where ST_DWithin(s1.the_geo, s2.the_geo, 50000);
```

However, to my surprise I found that although A and B are separated from each other by a distance greater than 50 km (50.0995 km to be precise. Found using Chris Veness's geodesy formulae​ (Calculate distance between a point and a line segment in latitude and longitude)), yet they are returned by postgres as results. Can someone please help me figure out as to where am I going wrong.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6devel and Postgis version which I am using is: POSTGIS="2.2.1 r14555"

Comment: You got an answer for that on the Postgres "Bugs" mailing list: "*I think you need to ask about that on the Postgis mailing lists, not here*" - did you do that? And why aren't you using a proper Postgres release?

Comment: Your code and sample data return a error by me: `ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "SRID=4326;POINT(0.628912,-" <-- parse error at position 26 within geometry`. Please add correct data and code examples

Comment: *"spatial coordinates expressed in (latitude, longitude (in degrees)) in postgres"* I think you need to pass arguments in longitude, latitude order. That is, first arg is longitude, not latitude. Could this be all or part of your problem?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I did insert spatial coordinates as (longitude, latitude) in postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did post on postgres mailing list. I am getting the same error even with proper postgres release

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico Try now

Comment: you should post it on the **PostGIS** mailing list, not the Postgres mailing list

Comment: Your coordinates are invalid lon/lat coordinates. Maybe are they in the reversed order? COPY returns this warning: `NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you're getting this on load..

```
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
CONTEXT:  COPY spatialtest, line 2, column the_geo: "SRID=4326;POINT(0.628912 -127.700922)"
```

Likely, you're trying to load `(lat,long)`, and PostgreSQL expects `(long,lat)`. However we can work around the ordering of your input column. All we have to do is,

1. Create a temp table `as`geometry`.

   ```
   CREATE TEMP TABLE foo(name text, the_geo geometry);
   ```
2. Chop off the SRID bit (EKWT) losing the SRID on import.

   ```
   sed -i -e's/SRID=4326;//' ./foo.csv
   ```
3. Load the input.

   ```
   \copy foo(name,the_geo) FROM 'foo.csv' DELIMITERS E'\t' CSV;
   ```
4. Reorder the points.
5. Copy into main table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO spatialTest(name, the_geo)
   SELECT
     name,
     ST_Union(
       ST_SetSRID(
         ST_MakePoint(st_y(geom), st_x(geom))
       ,4326)
     )::geography
   FROM foo
   CROSS JOIN ST_DumpPoints(foo.the_geo) AS t
   GROUP BY name
   ORDER BY name;
   ```

As a side note: don't use varchar for name. Just leave it as `TEXT`. Unless you have a good reason to impose a character limit.

Then run your distance..

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  (SELECT the_geo FROM spatialtest WHERE name='A'), (SELECT the_geo FROM spatialtest WHERE name='B')
);
  st_distance   
----------------
 49740.52214618
(1 row)
```

Comment: I tried with (long, lat) but still I am getting the same error

Comment: what do you mean same error, I just got the st_distance of 49.7 KM? what do you want?